# Bluescreen issues in windows 10 after dualbooting with Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I dualbooted Windows 10 with Ubuntu.But when i boot into windows i get a bluescreen after sometime stating PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA.What can be the cause?

Comment: Did you turn off fast startup in windows?

Comment: yes i did...but i turned off fast startup after installing ubuntu not before.

Comment: Windows problem (I haven't a clue how page faults are handled on Windows) see for example [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-update/blue-screen-pagefaultinnonpagedarea/602ebd62-8ade-4e29-b2b2-c779d5f469f4), ask about it on [SU] (Ubuntu is also on topic there)

Answer (score 3):

#### Correlation is not causation:

Unless you installed [Ubuntu On Windows](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/03/30/ubuntu-on-windows-the-ubuntu-userspace-for-windows-developers/), *which you obviously didn't as you're dual booting*:

- Ubuntu doesn't need Windows to run
- Ubuntu doesn't touch Windows to run (only the Windows boot loader gets replaced)
- Ubuntu doesn't use your Windows partition to do anything but store data (*if and only if* you actually mount the Windows partition)

So unless you went into the mounted Windows partition to delete files, Ubuntu cannot be the cause of the [BSOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death), so you should look into Windows itself for the cause, which makes your question off-topic here, but still on-topic over on https://superuser.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu.

### Sorry!

Comment: i installed ubuntu alongside windows manager and did'nt delete any of the windows files.

Comment: That's what I said: it's not an Ubuntu problem... so [go here](https://superuser.com) and ask your question there, providing much more windows information, like the memory dump.

Comment: Thank you for sending the link.I have posted the question there.Can it be a bootloader problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no, pure Windows problem...